# Serializing and Deserializing other than user model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

I have two schemas one for farmers and other for users but when serializing it is not working..
when in the registered all of the data goes to the Users model

```
const farmerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String
});

farmerSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

const Farmer = mongoose.model("Farmer", farmerSchema);

passport.use(Farmer.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(Farmer.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(Farmer.deserializeUser());



const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String,
  pattam: [{
    name: {
      type: String,
   unique: true
 },
    latitude: String,
    longitude: String,
    pattamdetails: String,
    pattamamount: String,
    pattamimg: {
      data: Buffer,
      contenttype: String
    }
  }]
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);


const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

//in the register route

```
app.post("/register", function(req,res){

  const farmerOrNot = req.body.radio;

  if(farmerOrNot === "yes"){

    Farmer.register({username: req.body.username},
    req.body.password, function(err,farmer){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect("/register");
      }else{
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
          res.redirect("/farmersPage");
        });
      }
    });

  }
  else{
  User.register({username: req.body.username},
  req.body.password, function(err,user){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect("/register");
    }else{
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
        res.redirect("/usersPage");
      });
    }
  });
  }


});
```

I want there to be different collections and for each of them to serialize and deserialize ..
Im new to development so don't know if there is any wrong